# flask StreamConsumingMiddleware no longer working

Tags: python, flask

I am getting a KeyError: 'CONTENT_LENGTH' error in my Flask application.  I haven't changed anything.  Actually, I let the project sit for 8 months, then formatted my harddrive and so I am downloading all the latest libraries for Flask-wtf etc.  The code that is a problem is here

> ```
>  def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
>     stream = LimitedStream(environ['wsgi.input'],
>                            int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'] or 0))
>     environ['wsgi.input'] = stream
>     app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
>     try:
>         stream.exhaust()
>         for event in app_iter:
>             yield event
>     finally:
>         if hasattr(app_iter, 'close'):
>             app_iter.close()
> ```

I have no idea what we use the LimtedStream for.  I added this two years ago.  There is [a bit about it here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/).  If I change the line to the following:

> stream = LimitedStream(environ['wsgi.input'], 0)

The home page loads but all my post forms stop working and I get 400 errors when posting anything.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I just had to wrap the environ in try catch.  So, I did something like this:

```
try:
       cont_len = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'] or 0) 
except Exception as e:
       cont_len = 0

stream = LimitedStream(environ['wsgi.input'], cont_len)
```